# Laravel limit departures to 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There is a problem with my part of the web-app that i'm making. The point is, for the user, if he intends to create a departure date (if he already has one) to display an error message like this: "Uh oh, you have already made a departure date. Delete the previously made departure date to assign a new one!"

DepartureController.php

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'departure_date' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
        'location' => 'required|max:1|integer|',


    ]);

    $date = Carbon::parse($request->departure_date);
    $LocationUsers = new LocationUser();
    $LocationUsers->user_id = request()->user()->id;
    $LocationUsers->departure_date = $date;
    $LocationUsers->location_id = $request->location;
    $LocationUsers->save();

    session()->flash('success', 'Departure added succesfully!');
    return redirect('departure/create');
}
```

And the User model

```
 public function daysUntilDeparture()
{
    if ($this->location()->count() < 1) {
        return "No departure date has been given";
    }

    $location = $this->location[0];

    $userLocation = LocationUser::where('user_id', $this->id)
        ->where('location_id', $location->id)
        ->first();

    $departure_date = $userLocation->departure_date;
    return $departure_date->diffInDays(Carbon::now());
}
```

Comment: This is not a question. But I guess you want an `unique` constraint

Comment: Yeah, what I actually meant to ask is the following: That the user may only have one departure date. And once it creates another departure date (whilst one existing) to display an error message that he already has one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own validation rule to do this (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules)

For example, your rule might look like:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class CurrentDeparture implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return is_null(LocationUser::where('user_id', request()->user()->id)->first());
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Uh oh, you have already made a departure date. Delete the previously made departure date to assign a new one!';
    }
}
```

And your validation would be:

```
$request->validate([
    'departure_date' => [new CurrentDeparture, 'required', 'date', 'after:yesterday'],
]);
```